# PhantomJS Screenshot run from angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, screenshot

I am looking for a HTML-to-PDF Converter and just stumble upon [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) 
I have set it up and can create a screenshot from the terminal but what i wanted is to have a button in my angularJS app that say's download PDF, then when clicked captures current PDF and begins downloading.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: PhantomJS can only run on the server. Written like this, you haven't mentioned what server environment you use. It is just too broad.

Comment: Thank you @ArtjomB. I am running an apache linux server, any pointers on how to go about this?